# Scipy ODE time steps going backward

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I've looked around on Stackoverflow, but could not find anything that would answer my question.

**Problem Setup:**

I am trying to solve a system of stiff ODEs using `scipy.integrate.ode`. I've reduced the code to the minimal working example:

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
spiketrain =[0]
syn_inst = 0

def synapse(t, t0):
    tau_1 = 5.3
    tau_2 = 0.05
    tau_rise = (tau_1 * tau_2) / (tau_1 - tau_2)
    B = ((tau_2 / tau_1) ** (tau_rise / tau_1) - (tau_2 / tau_1) ** (tau_rise / tau_2)) ** -1
    return B*(sp.exp(-(t - t0) / tau_1) - sp.exp(-(t - t0) / tau_2)) #the culprit

def alpha_m(v, vt):
    return -0.32*(v - vt -13)/(sp.exp(-1*(v-vt-13)/4)-1)

def beta_m(v, vt):
    return 0.28 * (v - vt - 40) / (sp.exp((v- vt - 40) / 5) - 1)

def alpha_h(v, vt):
    return 0.128 * sp.exp(-1 * (v - vt - 17) / 18)

def beta_h(v, vt):
    return  4 / (sp.exp(-1 * (v - vt - 40) / 5) + 1)

def alpha_n(v, vt):
    return -0.032*(v - vt - 15)/(sp.exp(-1*(v-vt-15)/5) - 1)

def beta_n(v, vt):
    return 0.5* sp.exp(-1*(v-vt-10)/40)

def inputspike(t):
    if int(t) in a :
        spiketrain.append(t)

def f(t,X):
    V = X[0]
    m = X[1]
    h = X[2]
    n = X[3]

    inputspike(t)
    g_syn = synapse(t, spiketrain[-1])
    syn = 0.5* g_syn * (V - 0)
    global syn_inst
    syn_inst = g_syn 

    dydt = sp.zeros([1, len(X)])[0]
    dydt[0] = - 50*m**3*h*(V-60) - 10*n**4*(V+100) - syn - 0.1*(V + 70)
    dydt[1] = alpha_m(V, -45)*(1-m) - beta_m(V, -45)*m
    dydt[2] = alpha_h(V, -45)*(1-h) - beta_h(V, -45)*h
    dydt[3] = alpha_n(V, -45)*(1-n) - beta_n(V, -45)*n
    return dydt

t_start = 0.0
t_end = 2000
dt = 0.1

num_steps = int(sp.floor((t_end - t_start) / dt) + 1)

a = sp.zeros([1,int(t_end/100)])[0]
a[0] = 500 #so the model settles
sp.random.seed(0)
for i in range(1, len(a)):
a[i] = a[i-1] + int(round(sp.random.exponential(0.1)*1000, 0))

r = integrate.ode(f).set_integrator('vode', nsteps = num_steps,
                                          method='bdf')
X_start = [-70, 0, 1,0]
r.set_initial_value(X_start, t_start)

t = sp.zeros(num_steps)
syn = sp.zeros(num_steps)
X = sp.zeros((len(X_start),num_steps))
X[:,0] = X_start
syn[0] = 0
t[0] = t_start
k = 1

while r.successful() and k < num_steps:
    r.integrate(r.t + dt)
    # Store the results to plot later
    t[k] = r.t
    syn[k] = syn_inst
    X[:,k] = r.y
    k += 1

plt.plot(t,syn)
plt.show()
```

**Problem:**

I find that when I actually run the code, time `t` in the solver appears to go back and forth, which results in `spiketrain[-1]` being greater than `t`, and the value `syn` becoming very negative and significantly messing up my simulations (you can see the negative values in the plot if the code is run).

I am guessing it has something to do with variable time steps in the solver, so I was wondering if it is possible to restrict time to only forward (positive) propagation.

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated the question with the minimal complete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solver do actually go back and forth, and I think also because of the variable time stepping. But I think the difficulty comes from that the result of `f(t, X)` is not only a function of `t` and `X` but of the previous call made to this function, which is not a good idea.

Your code works by replacing:

```
inputspike(t)
g_syn = synapse(t, spiketrain[-1])
```

by:

```
last_spike_date = np.max( a[a<t] )
g_syn = synapse(t, last_spike_date)
```

And by setting an "old event" for the "settle time" with `a = np.insert(a, 0, -1e4)`. This is needed to always have a `last_spike_date` defined (see the comment in the code below).

Here is a modified version of your code:

I modified how the time of the last spike if found (using this time the Numpy function [searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) so that the function can be vectorized).  I also modified the way the array `a` is created. This is not my field, so maybe I misunderstood the intent.

I used [`solve_ivp`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) instead of `ode` but still with a [BDF solver](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.BDF.html#scipy.integrate.BDF) (However it's not the same implementation as in `ode` which is in Fortran).

```
import numpy as np  # rather than scipy 
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def synapse(t, t0):
    tau_1 = 5.3
    tau_2 = 0.05
    tau_rise = (tau_1 * tau_2) / (tau_1 - tau_2)
    B = ((tau_2 / tau_1)**(tau_rise / tau_1) - (tau_2 / tau_1)**(tau_rise / tau_2)) ** -1
    return B*(np.exp(-(t - t0) / tau_1) - np.exp(-(t - t0) / tau_2))

def alpha_m(v, vt):
    return -0.32*(v - vt -13)/(np.exp(-1*(v-vt-13)/4)-1)

def beta_m(v, vt):
    return 0.28 * (v - vt - 40) / (np.exp((v- vt - 40) / 5) - 1)

def alpha_h(v, vt):
    return 0.128 * np.exp(-1 * (v - vt - 17) / 18)

def beta_h(v, vt):
    return  4 / (np.exp(-1 * (v - vt - 40) / 5) + 1)

def alpha_n(v, vt):
    return -0.032*(v - vt - 15)/(np.exp(-1*(v-vt-15)/5) - 1)

def beta_n(v, vt):
    return 0.5* np.exp(-1*(v-vt-10)/40)

def f(t, X):
    V = X[0]
    m = X[1]
    h = X[2]
    n = X[3]

    # Find the largest value in `a` before t:
    last_spike_date = a[ a.searchsorted(t, side='right') - 1 ]

    # Another simpler way to write this is:
    # last_spike_date = np.max( a[a<t] )
    # but didn't work with an array for t        

    g_syn = synapse(t, last_spike_date)
    syn = 0.5 * g_syn * (V - 0)

    dVdt = - 50*m**3*h*(V-60) - 10*n**4*(V+100) - syn - 0.1*(V + 70)
    dmdt = alpha_m(V, -45)*(1-m) - beta_m(V, -45)*m
    dhdt = alpha_h(V, -45)*(1-h) - beta_h(V, -45)*h
    dndt = alpha_n(V, -45)*(1-n) - beta_n(V, -45)*n
    return [dVdt, dmdt, dhdt, dndt]


# Define the spike events:
nbr_spike = 20
beta = 100
first_spike_date = 500

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.cumsum( np.random.exponential(beta, size=nbr_spike) ) + first_spike_date
a = np.insert(a, 0, -1e4)  # set a very old spike at t=-1e4
                           # it is a hack in order to set a t0  for t<first_spike_date (model settle time)
                           # so that `synapse(t, t0)` can be called regardless of t
                           # synapse(t, -1e4) = 0  for t>0

# Solve:
t_start = 0.0
t_end = 2000

X_start = [-70, 0, 1,0]

sol = solve_ivp(f, [t_start, t_end], X_start, method='BDF', max_step=1, vectorized=True)
print(sol.message)

# Graph
V, m, h, n = sol.y
plt.plot(sol.t, V);
plt.xlabel('time');  plt.ylabel('V');
```

which gives:

[image: result for V]

note:  There is an events parameters in `solve_ivp` which could be useful.